# I want to connect to a HOST with an oracle DB from a remote PC

Tags: oracle, configuration, listener, tnsnames

I am using PL/SQL Developer to connect to my home PC that has an oracleDB installed (up and running) from my remote laptop and I know that I must configure my tnsname and listener on the PC with the oracleDB to permit remote request (If I am not wrong). But I can't make it work keep gettin the error:

ora-12514 tns listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

My configs:
listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\UserNam\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS ="EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\Stefan\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home\bin\oraclr18.dll")
)
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = HOME)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\Stefan\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home)
      (SID_NAME = home)
   )
 )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 2484))
   )
 )
SANDBOX =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1522))
   )
 )
```

and tnsnames.ora

```
HOME =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = home)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LISTENER_HOME =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

Comment: I've done this in the past, but you have to figured out what port your going to allow to open on your router  some ISP routers have port forwarding that you can manipulate for this sort of situations.

Comment: There is port forwarding  allready present on my ports. I have checked , thanks

Comment: What services does the listener currently know of? Run `lsnrctl services` on the server for a list.

Comment: Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "HOME" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "home", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:7 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully